# Can I develop an application that extend Talkback functions on android?

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I want to develop an application that extend/change TalkBack functions.

For example: every time "TalkBack" reads a text from a Facebook post or a tweet or any other app, it says "I finished" at the end of every Facebook post or a tweet etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're called Accessibility Services on Android.  TalkBack is actually open source, probably the easiest place to start.

https://github.com/google/talkback

Comment: Do you know if there's a more updated version? The current version is the 8.1 and that repo has the 6.1